# Drupal 7 to Local Server

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I currently work for a company that is developing a web and mobile application. I've been programming for a while now, but am less familiar with web development. I previously had been writing specialized python scripts for the company; they wanted me to transition into developing their web app. The web dev is currently being outsourced, so there aren't employees at the company that are familiar with how the website was developed. The third party is aware of my task, but is not very helpful and would prefer I only make changes locally.

What I need to do :

I need to put the Drupal site onto a local server, so I can make changes without breaking what was previously built or being on the outsourced web server.

Site specs:
Drupal 7.52
mySQL
PHP 5.6.30-1
Apache/2.2.22

My specs:
Windows 10

I have the website files (code and database). I keep encountering the same error, and have tried a number of different solutions and web stacks. When I go to upload our database into phpMyAdmin, I get an error about the database being too large (unzipped, around 118,000 KB, zipped, around 12,000 KB). I have tried a number of workarounds, and keep falling short. I've changed max_allowed_packets, $cfg['UploadDir'], and many more recommendations given here on Stack Overflow.

I've uninstalled everything from my system, so I can just start over from scratch. If anyone can give a set of instructions for how I would take the website files, upload the large database, and then have a copy of the website on a local server, that would be miraculously helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a virtual machine like this project https://www.drupal.org/project/vdd, which has what you need for local development and you will not need to mess up with our local OS